# This webpage has a redirect loop in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The Goal is to redirect all users to my custom Security Page on each httpRequest as long as the Session variable is null or empty.

In Global.asax

The method causes an error as follows:

This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
  if ((Session["SecurityCodeApproved"] == null || !(bool)Session["SecurityCodeApproved"]))
  {
    Response.RedirectToRoute("Security");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are redirecting to the same page, checking if the session cookie is set, and if not, redirecting it again. Its going to continuously redirect itself, until a session cookie is set, and you aren't setting one. You need to either redirect elsewhere or set the cookie to break the loop.

Comment: How to check "session cookie is set" or not?

Comment: add an `else { //cookie is set }` after your if statement. (Your if statement checks if the cookie is NOT set, so if it is, you go into your else and can handle it.

Comment: When I try to run the code it catches another error on if statement "Session state is not available in this context."

Comment: Thats because you haven't handled the root cause, you've just added an IF statement that doesn't get hit. I don't know what you are trying to achieve, only you do. You need to decide what happens if the cookie isn't set, do they get taken to a "Access Denied" page? or a login page? or what?

Comment: I want to check the session value on each http request and if the session is null then redirect the user to to custom login page.

Comment: @arlen That's where you are going wrong, currently your statement says `if the cookie is not set, send them to the "Security" page`. You need to modify it to say `if the cookie is not set, send them to the "login" page, else, send them to the "Security" page`

Comment: but I don't want them to go to login page, as long as (Session["SecurityCodeApproved"] == null || !(bool)Session["SecurityCodeApproved"]) i want to redirect them to security page.

Comment: @arlen What exactly happens on security page? Is that a login or a landing page once logged in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18931/discussion-between-arlen-and-andy)

Answer (score 1):

Do not do this in your Global.asax because as you have noticed, you will not always have a session every time that event fires. Also your code will fire on **ALL** requests, including those for resources like css, images, and JavaScript.  What you want to do is use a **Global Filter Attribute** to perform your logic or if you are using WebForms, you want to do this at the Page Level.

When Filters are executed you are garaunteed a FilterContext that will have the request and the session objects you need.

You can then redirect to your security page, but make sure your filter attribute is ignored on your security point.

Comment: But how? Could you please provide me with an example?